# Drawing a trapezium with multiple-line text inside it

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using the following code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red, rotate=-90, trapezium stretches body, text width=3cm, align=center] at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{Investment}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How can I insert a 3-line text inside the trapezium without changing its dimensions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before and after:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz,stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red, rotate=-90, trapezium stretches body, 
  text width=3cm, align=center] at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{Investment}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red, rotate=-90, trapezium stretches body, 
  text width=3cm, align=center] at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{%
  \color{red}\Centerstack{My\\Big\\Investment}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a version without addition packages, using a `\parbox`.  However, the result is extremely sensitive to the `\parbox` width, here chosen precisely as 1.75cm:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red, rotate=-90, trapezium stretches body, 
  text width=3cm, align=center] at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{Investment}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red, rotate=-90, trapezium stretches body, 
  text width=3cm, align=center] at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{%
  \parbox{1.75cm}{\centering My\\Big\\Investment}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention that due to security reasons I can not install new packages into my workplace computer.

Comment: @Hany `stackengine` is standard for most distributions.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have it

Comment: @Hany You must have a very old installation.

Comment: Can it be done without using the stackengine. Thank you

Comment: @Hany See my edit, using `\parbox`.  Unfortunately, the specified width, if not chosen just so, will change the trapezoid shape.

Comment: Thank you. Could the text be centered inside the parbox

Comment: @Hany Sure.  I just added `\centering` at the appropriate spot.

Comment: @StevenThank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I would just rotate the border instead of first rotating the full thing and then rotating the text back. (Note that one has to feed in a bit counter-intuitive values in `shape border rotate` when not used with `shape uses incircle` because there is some strange rounding going on.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red, rotate=-90, trapezium stretches body, text width=3cm, 
align=center] at (0,0) {\rotatebox{90}{Investment}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.8, transform shape]
\node[draw, trapezium, red,minimum width=5.5cm,
shape border rotate=-135, trapezium stretches body, 
align=center] at (0,0) {Investment\\ Ducks\\ Latex};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmotThank you very much for your answer